# Paste command is not one to one

Tags: linux, command-line, cut, paste

I have a file called phone_dir.txt (2 lines for example):

```
ADAMS, Andrew 7583
BARRETT, Bruce 6466
```

I try to extract the last names and capitalize them, the output required is:

```
Adams
Barret
```

I can only use commands such as:

- cut
- paste
- tr

I tried running the following script but the results are inconsistent:

```
cut -c1 phone_dir.txt > last_names.txt | cut -f1 -d',' phone_dir.txt | cut -c2- | tr A-Z a-z | paste last_names.txt - | tr -d [:blank:]
```

Sometimes the output is:

```
Adams
Barret
```

And sometimes

```
dams
arret
```

Why are the results inconsistent?

Comment: `awk` or `perl` are more suited for this job... Is this homework ?

Comment: You're sending the output of cut into last_names.txt but also trying to pipe it ?  Unlikely you truly want to attempt both actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to create a temporary file, how about this?

```
in=phone_dir.txt
out=last_names.txt
tmp=$$tmp && \
a=$(cut -d',' -f1 "$in" | tee >(cut -c2- | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] > "$tmp") | cut -c1) && \
paste  <(printf "%s\n" ${a[@]}) "$tmp" | tr -d [:blank:] > "$out" && \
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: You inspired me by using '<()' to write this solution with no temp files:

cut -f1 -d',' phone_dir.txt | cut -c2- | tr A-Z a-z | paste <(cut -c1 phone_dir.txt) - | tr -d [:blank:] > last_names.txt

Comment: @DorShmaryahu Well done. Simpler and faster.